# Why do some elements such as polonium not follow the trend of decreasing atomic radius?

Tags: periodic-trends, atomic-radius

Most of the periodic table follows the trend of increasing radius as you move down a family and decreasing radius as you move across a period. Why is this trend not observed for polonium?